# Error in test[[1:3]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2

Tags: r, list

I am a newbie to R and subsetting the list like below:

```
test<-list(c(10,15,20,25),c(11,12,13,14),c(21,22,23,24))

test

[[1]]
[1] 10 15 20 25

[[2]]
[1] 11 12 13 14

[[3]]
[1] 21 22 23 24
```

now i am doing this

```
test<-test[[1:3]][1]
```

its showing below error

> Error in test[[1:3]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2

Comment: you probably need `sapply(test, `[[`, 1)`

Comment: Don't you need backticks around the `[[` when calling it like this?

Comment: Thank you ronak ..its working I did this  apply(test, "[[", 1)

Comment: now wat to do if i want first two or more values of each element of list

Comment: I have a vector like this

> a<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

I want to retrieve only 4,5,6,7 from the vector a.

how i can do that ?

Answer (score 1):

To select more than 1 value from each list you could use `sapply`/`lapply`. For example, to select first 3 values from the list you could do

```
lapply(test, `[`, 1:3)

#[[1]]
#[1] 10 15 20

#[[2]]
#[1] 11 12 13

#[[3]]
#[1] 21 22 23
```

Or with `sapply` you'll get the same result but in matrix form where each column represents the value from the list.

```
sapply(test, `[`, 1:3)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   10   11   21
#[2,]   15   12   22
#[3,]   20   13   23
```

Comment: one more issue...  I have a vector like this

> a<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

I want to retrieve only 4,5,6,7 from the vector a.

how i can do that ?

Comment: @mohitji you could use `match`, `a[!is.na(match(a, 4:7))]` and it will return you only values that have `4:7`.

Answer (score 0):

[To quote from the documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) (emphasis mine):

> The most important distinction between `[`, `[[` and `$` is that the **`[` can select more than one element whereas the other two select a single element**.

In other words `test[[1 : 3]]` doesn’t do what you presumably think it does. Instead, it attempts to perform *recursive* subsetting, which is equivalent to writing `test[[1L]][[2L]][[3L]]`.

As suggested in the comments, you need to perform something along the lines of `` lapply(test, `[[`, 1L) `` to subset each vector in your list. To have the result as a vector rather than a list, wrap the call in `unlist`, or use `vapply`:

```r
vapply(test, `[[`, numeric(1L), 1L)
```

You can also use `sapply` instead of the latter but beware that this function coerces its return value in not ways that are not always obvious, and are therefore error-prone. It’s better to restrict its use to interactive sessions.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `head` with `lapply`

```
lapply(test, head, 3)
#[[1]]
#[1] 10 15 20

#[[2]]
#[1] 11 12 13

#[[3]]
#[1] 21 22 23
```

---

Or using `map` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map(test, head, 3)
```

---

For subsetting vector values, we can use `%in%`

```
a[a %in% 4:7]
```